# Not able to find Timer Job "Information Management Policy" in job definitions

Tags: timer-jobs

I deleted the timer job "Information Management Policy" by mistake.

I tried to restore it using ensuredefaultjobs() method but i am not able to restore it .

I am not able to see the job in the job definition as well .

Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: https://spsawyer.wordpress.com/2015/11/06/sharepoint-restoring-an-ootb-timer-job/

Comment: Thank you so much Christoffer .....it worked like a charm !!!!.  I was not able to find the assembly initially but found it with this URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to update you need to find the Microsoft. Office. Policy assembly which contains this Information management policy job.
Once you find it, you need to update this assembly in your Web application.
Do not forget to perform an IISRESET. Sometimes it takes two to three attempts before this service starts reflecting in your Web application.

Answer (score 0):

If `ensuredefaultjobs()` is not working for you then try to find the assembly that contains this "Information Management Policy" timer job.

Then Update this assembly in web application. This will solve your issue.

Comment: have you tried this?